# Linking Geymotion with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, genymotion

I tried to link the Genymotion emulator plugin with the ADT for Eclipse and I had the following error:

[image]

an you please help me find the reason for this error?

Comment: "I have already googled it and tried many solutions on SO but in vain." What makes your situation different from those questions? I'd rather aggregate solutions on a single question if those are duplicates.

Comment: May be because Eclipse ADP is no longer supported by Google? Using it only causes problems and trouble.